# What happened to Feral Flare?

Tags: league-of-legends

I remember when Feral Flare came out that everyone used to build it in certain junglers.

Then it got some nerfs and everyone stopped building it. Even pro-players. I never thought it was a huge nerf. I still think it is a good item.

Lately I've jungling more (I main Xin Zhao jungle) and I noticed even with other xin zhao junglers that they don't build Feral Flare. My build path with Xin Zhao normally goes:

**Wriggles-Lantern -> Simple Boots -> Blade of the Ruined King -> Youmoos -> (tank items)**

I have a pretty sick record with this build. I rarely lose with this. And as soon as Wriggles Lantern turns into Feral Flare the power spike really turns up a lot. I understand that if the game isn't going well it might not be good but I don't understand why people don't give it a chance.

Is there something I'm missing? Why the hate on Feral Flare? Why are the other items better for pros and people in general to build and in what situations?

Comment: jutschge... you are called for duty to officialy hate on Feral Flare!

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW on it!

Comment: i like feral flare :( but only on Udyr

Comment: there were hard nerves in 4.7 http://na.leagueoflegends.com/en/news/game-updates/patch/patch-47-notes#patch-feral-flare-line

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW I know there were nerves. But i still build on my Xin and wreck face with it. Even on games where the team isn't ahead. As soon as I hit that wriggles I get super good at farming and ganking. and when the feral flare comes no one is safe.

Comment: @Lokuzt this sounds like a stupid question, but have you tried elder lizard? maybe you wreck even more ;)

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Yes. I've tried elder lizard on Xin on about 4 straight games. I eventually went back to Feral Flare. As I said it never lets me down with him. Feral Flare depends on the champ. But I still think that some champs are really good with Feral like WW, Xin and Godyr

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are two main reasons to this.

**Mental aspect**
Feral flare has a quite bad reputation right now. Mainly because people often associate it with the "Afkfarming Jungler" since it requires you to kill jungle camps to gain extra stacks (or even the item itself). Then again this reputation doesn't come out of nowhere. At the release of the item a lot of junglers just went up farming for 30 minutes straight and while yes, they were strong after these 30 minutes, their team often lost due to the fact that they were basically playing a 4v5.

**The Stats and gold efficiency**
Let's face it... Feral flare has horrible stats for most junglers. The item itself is worth 74% of its value and the passive requires you to **kill a big monster for 1 extra damage**. That means at best if you are **only** afkfarming in the jungle you might get 3 extra damage per minute and you also need to be farming all day to compensate for the gold income. Also the 10 health on return are not really great. The only thing it's really good for are the high-range ward and the faster clearing of objectives like Baron, Dragon or buffs.

Now I'm not saying that it is a horrible item per se but all the other jungle items are a lot better. Elder Lizard provides you with more Damage through his AD + True damage and Ancient Golem gives you a ton of tankiness and on top of that both items will provide you with an insane amount of HP and Mana sustain.

The nerfs Hit feral flare really hard mainly because you need more stacks and because they nerfed the Attackspeed on the item. Xin-Zhao is literally the only champion where you could still consider buying it if you just look at the stats but then again: You'd have to farm a lot to benefit from the item and this is almost impossible since  Xin is among the slowest junglers in the game.

**It's better to just go for either Golem or Lizard on these champions while ganking alot instead of buying an item that is useless if you're not afk farming**

Comment: you also gain 30% more gold from monsters which leads to an early gold lead in most games. (if you just AFK farm)

Comment: @DropDeadSander-EUW Yeah but you'll also get gold stacks on the other items and these can stack up on while you're ganking. For the extra gold on FF you need to be farming all day. On Lizard for example you can gank top -> Golems -> gank mid -> wraiths and you'd have done more for your team than if you wanted the same amount of gold with feral flare.

Comment: thats why i said: if you just AFK farm. totally agree! i switched to elder lizard on many champions is used to build FF with.

Comment: I think you guys would kill me if I told you I build Spirit of the Spectral Wraith on Amumu xD And it is pretty good I must admit xD

Comment: @Lokuzt Well Wraith is pretty decent on amumu. Personally I prefer Golem but Wraith is great for some extra damage + clearspeed early.

Comment: I might want to argue that it's not useless if you aren't AFK farming.  I build it on Poppy jungle all the time.  It really helps her clear and I go for a more AS build rather than a burst build.  I still gank and countergank as well.  FF allows me to not burn mana in order to farm.  It also helps her clear more than anything which leaves her healthy for fighting enemies.  Just because you get FF doesn't mean you need to AFK farm.  Sure it upgrades for me about 5 min later but I'm still about making plays for my team.  (I do hate it on most junglers though still)

Comment: You can't kill [alot](http://3.bp.blogspot.com/_D_Z-D2tzi14/S8TTPQCPA6I/AAAAAAAACwA/ZHZH-Bi8OmI/s400/ALOT2.png), he's not in the game yet.

Comment: I'd also like to note that Feral Flare no longer exists on the PBE for the upcoming preseason and is replace by a much more powerful enchantment Devourer: http://leagueoflegends.wikia.com/wiki/Devourer. It has proved to be pretty overpowering with champions like Warwick and will likely get the numbers tuned down a bit but there is no longer a farm requirement so less afk junglers yay!

Answer (score 2):

**Because it's not very gold-efficient, and its not really that good in most builds, its very specialized.**

> That said, it's still broken on some junglers imo. Warwick and Xin come immediately to mind- BotRK, Feral Flare, and they're already virtually unkillable (At least before you die, in Xin's case. He doesn't have that much sustain.), never mind before tank items.

So really it's not hated in most cases, people don't use it because it's a very specialized build for it to be worthwhile.

> You can't. It's simply not viable now. You need at least two items (generally feral+BoTRK) to be effective. If you just go feral then full tank, you're not taking advantage of the item at all, and you're trading your first 15+ minutes to do it.

A good discussion can be found [here](http://www.reddit.com/r/summonerschool/comments/241ycq/is_feral_flare_still_very_strong_post_nerf/).

Comment: trivial info: you can only buy it on summoners rift. there is a slightly different item for other maps.